# JDK dns not respect system dns setting in kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes

I custom the k8s core dns file to resolve a custom name.which works fine in pods checked by ping xx.
But it not resolved in java appliation(jdk14).
Nameserver is ok.

```
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search xxxx-5-production.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local

/ # ping xx
PING xx (192.168.65.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.65.2: seq=0 ttl=37 time=0.787 ms
```

Edit: I use coredns rewrite host name `xx` to `host.docker.internal`,this is change to coredns config

```
    rewrite name regex (^|(?:\S*\.)*)xx\.?$ {1}host.docker.internal
```

I add some debug code to the entry:

```
  static void runCommand(String... commands)  {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder cat = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
            Process start = cat.start();
            start.waitFor();
            String output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(start.getInputStream())).lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
            String err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(start.getErrorStream())).lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
            log.info("\n{}: stout {}", Arrays.toString(commands),output);
            log.info("\n{}: sterr{}", Arrays.toString(commands),err);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            log.error(e.getClass().getCanonicalName(), e);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InetAddress xx = Inet4Address.getByName("xx");
            log.info("{}: {}", "InetAddress xx", xx.getHostAddress());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getClass().getCanonicalName(), e);
        }
        runCommand("cat", "/etc/resolv.conf");
        runCommand("ping", "xx","-c","1");
        runCommand("ping", "host.docker.internal","-c","1");
        runCommand("nslookup", "xx");
        runCommand("ifconfig");
        SpringApplication.run(FileServerApp.class, args);
    }
```

Here is output:

```
01:01:39.950 [main] ERROR com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp - java.net.UnknownHostException
java.net.UnknownHostException: xx: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:932)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:851)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1495)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1354)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1288)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1238)
    at com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp.main(FileServerApp.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
01:01:39.983 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[cat, /etc/resolv.conf]: stout nameserver 10.96.0.10search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.localoptions ndots:5
01:01:39.985 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[cat, /etc/resolv.conf]: sterr
01:01:39.991 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[ping, xx, -c, 1]: stout
01:01:39.991 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[ping, xx, -c, 1]: sterrping: unknown host
01:01:39.998 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[ping, host.docker.internal, -c, 1]: stout PING host.docker.internal (192.168.65.2): 56 data bytes64 bytes from 192.168.65.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=37 time=0.757 ms--- host.docker.internal ping statistics ---1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet lossround-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.757/0.757/0.757/0.000 ms
01:01:39.998 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[ping, host.docker.internal, -c, 1]: sterr
01:01:40.045 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[nslookup, xx]: stout Server:       10.96.0.10Address:  10.96.0.10#53Non-authoritative answer:Name: host.docker.internalAddress: 192.168.65.2** server can't find xx: NXDOMAIN
01:01:40.045 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[nslookup, xx]: sterr
01:01:40.048 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[ifconfig]: stout eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500        inet 10.1.3.14  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0        ether ce:71:60:9a:75:05  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)        RX packets 35  bytes 3776 (3.6 KiB)        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0        TX packets 22  bytes 1650 (1.6 KiB)        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)        RX packets 1  bytes 29 (29.0 B)        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0        TX packets 1  bytes 29 (29.0 B)        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
01:01:40.048 [main] INFO com.j.file_server_app.FileServerApp -
[ifconfig]: sterr
```

Looks like coredns not working,but in the front end pod,ping is ok,this is front end `Dockerfile`

```
FROM library/nginx:stable-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
EXPOSE 80
ADD dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Using `docker inspect` for fontend and backend container,both network setting are:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {},
    "SandboxKey": "",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {}
}
```

Both frontend and backend has service with   `type: LoadBalancer`,now my question is why the name resolve behave different in this two pods?

Comment: Could you give more precision about what the Java application calls to resolve the name? Is it `InetAddress.getAllByName`? `InetAddress` relies on `getaddrinfo` to perform name resolution.

Comment: `InetAddress xx = Inet4Address.getByName("xx");` and spring boot oauth cannot access endpoint cause by host name not resolved

Comment: Thanks. Do you modify resolv.conf before or after the java application is started? InetAddress has a cache of resolved/failed lookups. If the cache says that the lookup for xx has failed it might not be attempted again. The InetAddress Java API documentation has some words about system properties that control the caching policy.

Comment: It seems that dns resolve behave different in two pods,and i cannot see the significant difference between this two,I did some digging and reedit the question

Comment: > why the name resolve behave different in this two pods?

I am afraid I can't answer that. All I can say is that `InetAddress` uses `getaddrinfo` to do name resolution - so if your changes have no influence on the results returned by `getaddrinfo` then `InetAddress` won't see them. Hope this helps!